# file upload file size for multiple files asp .net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to upload the multiple files an asp.net website using `asp:FileUpload` control.
Everything is working fine but I need to save each file size into database.

I was trying to loop through files using

`foreach (var file in fil_AttachmentLink.PostedFiles)`
and getting file size by `file.ContentLength`
but its always `0`.

I also tried 
`for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)`
    and `Request.Files[i].ContentLength`
but that is also `0`.

What could I use to achieve what I want?

Comment: I have found that you can lose the file itself during postback... watch out for that.

Comment: How many files do you upload, and what is `Request.Files.Count`? Can you skip the zero-length files?

Comment: at least 1 file up to 10. Request.Files.Count is a number of files in the request.

Comment: I am able to access file size on client like so:
for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
    fileSize += this.files[i].size; // total files size
}
I need a same thing on the server. 
Is asp:FileUpload the way to go?
how about telerik control? Would that give me a file size on server side?
All I can think of now is to store file size csv in hidden field each time files change to access those on server.
It is a work around but it seems silly.
why ContentLength is 0???

Comment: Sorry logixologist, could you expand on possibility of losing file? In what scenario is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I have achieve what I wanted but I am not proud of the way its done so if anyone can advice less "dirty" way I would be thankful..
Here is what I've done,
client side -> store all files sizes in Hidden Field on each file change as below:

```
 $('#<%= fil_AttachmentLink.ClientID %>').change(function () {
            fileSize = 0;
            var allSizes = "";
            if (this.files[0]) {// file exists 
                if (this.files.length > 1)
                    $('.fileUploader').find("span").html(this.files.length + " files selected");
                for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
                    fileSize += this.files[i].size; // total files size  
                    allSizes = allSizes + this.files[i].size + ",";
                }
                allSizes = allSizes.substring(0, allSizes.length - 1); // remove last comma
            }
            $('#<%= hf_FileSize.ClientID %>').val(allSizes);
        });
```

server side - get list of ints from hidden field as below:

```
 List<int> sizes = (hf_FileSize.Value.Split(',').Select<string, int>(int.Parse)).ToList();
```

Next loop through each file and access all properties I need and sizes from above list

```
for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
{
    string ext = (Path.GetExtension(Request.Files[i].FileName));
    string docName = Request.Files[i].FileName.Replace(ext, "");
    int fileSize = sizes[i];
    // save to database etc...
}
```

Again it works but I hope there is a better way...

Answer (score -1):

It's very easy to accomplish. After you do your primary code for html, then you can start with the actual coding. I have a link from code project that explains from step 1 to the finish line. I have used this several times http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1757/File-Upload-with-ASP-NET I think this is what your looking for.. Let me know if it works out for you.

Comment: Don't just link to a blog post http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer 

Here is more guidance on how to craft a good answer for the stackoverflow site. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: An answer is an answer, if I was to explain the whole thing then people like you will say its to long. If I post a short version, then people like you say its too short.. So he asked a question and I gave him an answer. If it helps him then good. If not then someone else will answer. It's not all about votes, rates and points. So you can take that else where. I am helping people so if you want to troll then go bother someone else.

Comment: No, your answer does not answer the question at all. The OP is asking why the files report a length of 0, which is not answered in your answer, nor in the page you link to.

Comment: He wasnt trying to troll. Its valid feedback.  If you have a link, its best to just put it in as a comment. Other sites are filled with simple link answers and you end up just chasing down a lot of useless leads. Referencing the link is fine, but you didnt really answer his question on why his file lengths were 0.

Comment: Well then instead of trolling, answer his question. @CodeCaster

Comment: As I said, that link is the whole process, if it helps then it helps... I will put everything in a comment but then it will bug me because its not a comment, it's an answer.. Besides we should be helping each other.. Not trolling.

Comment: Dumping a link to a very old, inaccurate and generic article is not equal to helping people. The OP's question is not _"Show me a tutorial for file uploads "_.

Comment: @CodeCaster You should change your username to TrollMaster.. Drop it already.